# Output raw XML using php

Tags: php, xml

I want to output raw xml in a manner similar to http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Mountain+View but using PHP.

I have a very simple php script on my webserver:

```
<?php 

      $output = "<root><name>sample_name</name></root>";
      print ($output);
?>
```

All I can see in Chrome/firefox is "sample_name". I want to see:

```
<root>
     <name>sample_name</name>
</root>
```

I cannot find a tutorial for anything THIS simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

By default PHP sets the Content-Type to text/html, so the browsers are displaying your XML document as an HTML page.

For the browser to treat the document as XML you have to set the content-type:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

Do this before printing anything in your script.

Comment: I just realised that I never marked this as correct - sorry about that

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    $output = "<root><name>sample_name</name></root>";
    print ($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

For completeness sake, as nobody's mentioned it yet, you can also output raw XML *within* an HTML page, by escaping `<` as `&lt;`, `>` as `&gt;`, and `&` as `&amp;`. To do that, use the awkwardly named [`htmlspecialchars` function](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Often, you'll also want to preserve whitespace in the argument, which can be done by surrounding it in `<pre>` tags. So a common line for debugging or including a sample is this:

```
 echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($raw_xml) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion... simple and easy.

Answer (score 4):

You only see "sample_name" because you didn't specify that your output is XML and the browser thinks it's HTML so your XML-Elements are interpreted as HTML-Elements.

To see the raw XML, you need to tell the browser that you're actually sending XML by sending the correct content-type in the HTTP header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
```

This needs to be send (put in the code) before you put out anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (Control+U), Your browser will display the page's raw source code under a new Tab, be it XML or HTML or whatever else...