# php make xml code but browser open in html

Tags: php, xml

I create the page http://omenorpreco.com/sitemap_index.xml for google read and identify all my pages.

but, when access this page, the XML dont open in xml mode.

if i view source of this page, copy and past in a file on my desktop and open in brownser, this file open correctly

What is wrong?

```
  <?php
    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";?>
        <sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<?php
        header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        $sql = "SELECT ceil(count(*)/5000) as total FROM `produto_price`";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
        <sitemap>
            <loc>http://omenorpreco.com/sitemap-categoria.xml</loc>
            <lastmod><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></lastmod>
        </sitemap>
<?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= $row['total']; $i++) : ?>
            <sitemap>
                <loc>http://omenorpreco.com/sitemap-<?php echo $i ; ?>.xml</loc>
                <lastmod><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></lastmod>
            </sitemap>
<?php 
        endfor 
?>
    </sitemapindex>
```

My .htaccess file redirect to url_amigavel.php

And url_amigavel.php include the file sitemap_index.php

Comment: the header **first**, then the output.

Comment: @fusion3k Add that as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output raw XML using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139708/output-raw-xml-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
    $sql    = "SELECT ceil(count(*)/5000) as total FROM `produto_price`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://omenorpreco.com/sitemap-categoria.xml</loc>
        <lastmod><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></lastmod>
    </sitemap>
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $row['total']; $i++): ?>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://omenorpreco.com/sitemap-<?php echo $i ; ?>.xml</loc>
        <lastmod><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></lastmod>
    </sitemap>
<?php endfor; ?>
</sitemapindex>
```