# RESOLVED: Random <head/> tag showing up in sitemap.xml and rss.xml

Tags: php, xml, rss

There's a random `<head/>` tag showing up in my RSS and Sitemap files online. It's nowhere in my code.

I've built a site from PHP/SQL from scratch and I'm trying to get the sitemap and rss files to format properly. I'm using PHP to generate the code and using htaccess to redirect sitemap.php and rss.php to sitemap.xml and rss.xml.

I'm using https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html for formatting.

The online files are here (view page source to see stray `<head/>` just before `<urlset..)`:
https://www.cognitame.com/sitemap.xml
https://www.cognitame.com/rss.xml

Sitemap.php

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

require('../db_connect.php');
$q = 'SELECT published_time FROM posts ORDER BY published_time DESC LIMIT 1';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    $published_time = $row['published_time']; }

// Homepage, modified time is when last blog was published
echo '<url>
    <loc>https://cognitame.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>'. $published_time . '</lastmod>
</url>';

// Loop through pages, list them
$q = 'SELECT link, modified_time FROM pages ORDER BY modified_time DESC';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<url>
        <loc>' . $row['link'] . '</loc>
        <lastmod>' . $row['modified_time'] . '</lastmod>
    </url>';
}

// Loop through all posts, list them
$q = 'SELECT link, modified_time FROM posts ORDER BY modified_time DESC';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<url>
        <loc>' . $row['link'] . '</loc>
        <lastmod>' . $row['modified_time'] . '</lastmod>
    </url>';
}

echo '</urlset>';

?>
```

rss.php

```
    echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:blogChannel="http://backend.userland.com/blogChannelModule">

    <channel>
    <title>Cognitame</title>
    <link>https://cognitame.com</link>
    <description>A personal coding and web development playground.</description>
    <language>en-us</language>';

    // Loop through all posts to print out RSS feed
    require('../db_connect.php');
    $q = 'SELECT post_id, title, link, description FROM posts ORDER BY post_id
        ASC';
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo'<item>
            <title>' . $row['title'] . '</title>
            <link>' . $row['link'] . '</link>
            <description>' . $row['description'] . '</description>
        </item>';
    }

    echo '</channel>
    </rss>';
?>
```

The end output I'm expecting is formatting like this for both:
https://www.sitemaps.org/sitemap.xml

Comment: This is the updated code as is uploaded on the server. I've made plenty of other edits on these files to know that they are updating.

Comment: First it may be worth setting the output format to xml(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139708/output-raw-xml-using-php), I would also recommend building the XML with an API rather than as a string.  Although this won't in theory alter the content, it will ensure that the content is well formed, something that future programmers/alterations may cause problems with.

Comment: Yes, that definitely helped.. although not with syntax errors. But thank you. :)

As for an API... why would you ever go thrid party for sitemap or RSS? Even if you're using wordpress or something like that it's generated locally. Generated by something that isn't running on your local server sounds really unreliable.